# How to fix input size of Dense Layer in CNN Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to build a face recognition model using keras. I have images with names of the subjects and features (not a lot for deep learning, I know but i'll get some more soon)

But when i try to fit my data i got this error :

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 243, 320, 3)

I've tried to change loss function from `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`.

With one-hot encoded labels using the "to_categorical" function of keras

But it won't work

Here is how i fill my lists with images and labels

```
###### fill with images
for i in range(0,num_classes):
k=0
for j in range(len(features)):
    k+=1
    if(i < 10):
        sub = "subject0"+str(i)+"."+features[j]+".png"
    else:
        sub = "subject"+str(i)+"."+features[j]+".png"
    imgfile = Image.open(sub)
    img = np.array(imgfile)
    #print(img.shape)
    #print(type(img))
    if(k != 3):
        train.append(img)
        train_labels.append(i)
    else :
        test.append(img)
        test_labels.append(i)

########## train 
train = np.asarray(train)
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels)

########## test 
test = np.asarray(test)
test_labels = np.asarray(test_labels)
```

My number of class is 3 for now ! (1 class is one subject)

Following is how  images are reshaped and normalised.

```
# Reshape  243x320 pixels, 1 channel (B/W)
train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
# Reshape  243x320 pixels, 1 channel (B/W)
test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)

# Normalize pixel values: [0-255] --> [0.0-1.0]
train, test = train / 255.0, test / 255.0

# One-hot encode labels
test = to_categorical(test, num_classes)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes)
```

I build a simple CNN model

```
######### build cnn models

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 128
epochs = 10

model.fit(train, test, validation_data=(train_labels, test_labels), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

I think the problem is the output of one of my layer from my model. I've tried to move the flatten but it hasn't worked.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `test = to_categorical(test, num_classes)` should be `train_labels = ...` instead and your `model.fit(...)` call should be `model.fit(train, train_labels)`.

These are the most striking errors I could find.